# Python read file containing numbers in a column and use these number for a command

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a script with Python. I have a .txt file containing a column with numbers in this format (example) `198900.000`. The idea is to read these numbers one by one and one by one use them as an input for a command:

1. Python reads the first number;
2. Python use the number as input in the command;
3. The command writes an output named, let's say, 'output_number'
   The command should run iteratively until the end of the column (the number of rows is unknown).

Can you please help me? Thank you!

Comment: Post a sample of the `.txt` file along with what you've already tried so far, thank you!

Comment: Did you get anywhere e.g. open the file, read the lines, maybe even convert the lines to float values?

Comment: The .txt format is the following (it's a column):

... 
600.000
630.000
640.000
650.000
660.000
680.000
690.000
720.000
740.000
750.000
770.000
780.000
800.000
810.000
820.000
830.000
840.000
850.000
860.000
3310.000
...

Comment: do you only have one column per row with one number? you should edit the question and show us the proper structure of the txt file

Comment: @Valerio What is your desired output? just the print of the number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

list.txt:

```
600.000
630.000
640.000
650.000
660.000
680.000
690.000
720.000
740.000
750.000
770.000
780.000
800.000
810.000
820.000
830.000
840.000
850.000
860.000
3310.000
```

**Perhaps**:

```
print(open("list.txt").read().split())
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
['600.000', '630.000', '640.000', '650.000', '660.000', '680.000', '690.000', '720.000', '740.000', '750.000', '770.000', '780.000', '800.000', '810.000', '820.000', '830.000', '840.000', '850.000', '860.000', '3310.000']
```

**OR**

```
with open("list.txt","r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for x in lines:
        print("output_number: {}".format(x))
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
output_number: 600.000

output_number: 630.000

output_number: 640.000

output_number: 650.000

output_number: 660.000
.
.
.
```

**EDIT**:

**OP**: *Python has to read the firts number and, for the firts number do a command. For example: Python reads the firts number '600.00' and then do (I write the command so could be clear) ' `gmx trjconv -dump 600.00 -output dump_600.00` '. Then Python has to repeat the same for all the number that are present in the column*

```
commands_list = { 'clear': ' gmx trjconv -dump XxX -output dump_XxX '}

def callCommand(x):
    cmd = input("Enter command:")
    if cmd in commands_list:
        print(commands_list[cmd].replace("XxX", x))
    else:
        print("Command does not exit, quiting")
        exit()



with open("list.txt","r") as f:
    lines=f.readlines()
    for x in lines:
        callCommand(x)
        print("output_number: {}".format(x))
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
Enter command:clear
 gmx trjconv -dump 600.000
 -output dump_600.000

output_number: 600.000

Enter command:blahhh
Command does not exit, quiting
```

Comment: Maybe I was not clear. Python has to read the firts number and, for the firts number do a command. For example: Python reads the firts number '600.00' and then do (I write the command so could be clear) ' gmx trjconv -dump 600.00 -output dump_600.00 '. Then Python has to repeat the same for all the number that are present in the column

Comment: @Valerio you need to write a dict containing those commands with key,value and after each iteration call the desired command append the number with it!

Comment: In principle you can avoid storing the list of numbers but iteratively use the extracted value for your line of code.

Comment: @Valerio and don't forget to accept it if it's the solution you were looking for. DirtyBit really went the extra mile to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you only have that one column with the number.

If you have more than one column you can use the `fieldnames` attribute to pinpoint your column.

```
import csv

output_number=list()
with open('yourfiledirectory\yourfile.txt', 'r') as f:
    df=csv.reader(f)
    for row in df:
       output_number.append(row)
```

Comment: `output.number.append(row) ` should be `output_number.append(row)`

Comment: Thanks, didn't notice the typo =). I am still unsure about the format of the input txt thou